# the operations on the dict aren't effective

Tags: python, pandas

I'm dealing with financial datas in order set up some volatiliy forecast models. I created a dictionary named `indices` containing my assets.

I have to add some columns to each asset's dataframe in the dict. After looping and especially using `indices[key]` and `value`, i am acutally stuck.

```py
indices = dict(AEX = df[df.Symbol==".AEX"],AORD = df[df.Symbol==".AORD"],BFX = df[df.Symbol==".BFX"])

ict_items([('AEX', Unnamed: 0 Symbol    ...      Rvol    LogRvol
0     2000-01-03 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.000580  -7.453228
1     2000-01-04 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  5.646706   1.731072
2     2000-01-05 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.014028  -4.266704
3     2000-01-06 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.862001  -0.148499
4     2000-01-07 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  3.128320   1.140496
5     2000-01-10 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.129058  -2.047497
6     2000-01-11 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.782647  -0.245074
7     2000-01-12 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.271311  -1.304490
8     2000-01-13 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.071858  -2.633065
9     2000-01-14 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.727395  -0.318286

for key,value in indices.items():
    indices[key] = value.reset_index(drop = True)
    rv1 = np.full((len(value.index),1),0,dtype=float)
    rv5 = np.full((len(value.index),1),0,dtype=float)
    rv22 = np.full((len(value.index),1),0,dtype=float)
    for j in list(range(22, len(value.index), 1)):
        rv1[j] = value.iloc[j-1]['LogRvol']
        rv5[j] = np.mean(value.iloc[j - 5:j]['LogRvol'])
        rv22[j] =  np.mean(value.iloc[j - 22:j]['LogRvol'])
    indices[key] = pd.concat([value,pd.DataFrame(rv1),pd.DataFrame(rv5),pd.DataFrame(rv22)],axis=1)
    indices[key] = value.iloc[22:]
    indices[key] = value.reset_index(drop=True)
```

after running the code, i expect an updated dict items which actually they are not.

here is the expected and inachieved result

```py
indices = dict(AEX = df[df.Symbol==".AEX"],AORD = df[df.Symbol==".AORD"],BFX = df[df.Symbol==".BFX"])

ict_items([('AEX', Unnamed: 0 Symbol    ...      Rvol    LogRvol rv1 rv5 rv22
0     2000-02-03 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.000580  -7.453228 
1     2000-02-04 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  5.646706   1.731072 -7.453228 
2     2000-02-05 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.014028  -4.266704 1.731072
3     2000-02-06 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.862001  -0.148499 -4.266704
4     2000-02-07 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  3.128320   1.140496 -0.148499
5     2000-02-10 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.129058  -2.047497 ..etc
6     2000-02-11 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.782647  -0.245074 
7     2000-02-12 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.271311  -1.304490 
8     2000-02-13 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.071858  -2.633065 
9     2000-02-14 00:00:00+00:00   .AEX  ...  0.727395  -0.318286
```

Comment: Can you have a small example of your initial dict, your final (wrong) dict and what your expected dict should look like.

Comment: I don't understand how you're expecting the code to work. Why are you repeatedly changing the same `indices[key]` within the same loop? In particular, when you do `indices[key] = pd.concat([value,pd.DataFrame(rv1),pd.DataFrame(rv5),pd.DataFrame(rv22)],axis=1)` and then immediately `indices[key] = value.iloc[22:]`, what are you expecting to happen to the first value?

Comment: Hey Karl, for example: on the 10th row of the dataframe, i'll porovide to ```rv1``` and ```rv5``` a result, but no to ```rv22```. as a matter of fact, i need for each row the a value for each rv in order to regress ```rv1``` againt ```rv5``` and ```rv22```. as ```rv22``` starts generating data only from the 23rd row, so all the data from 0 to 22nd row is usless and then i delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for-loop in your example overwrites the value of `indices[key]` 4 times.

Your code is therefore equivalent to:

```
for key, value in indices.items():
    indices[key] = value.reset_index(drop=True)
```

which apparently does not change the value of `indices[key]`.

Note that it's generally not a good idea to update the item you are iterating over, in this case `indices`.

Comment: Do you sugget that i replace ```value``` by ```indices[key]```?

As the assets were ```vtacked```, subsetting them took also their original index. As I wanted that the nested loop works, i had to normalize the index.